# Por que "habrás visto" en vez de "verás" o "has visto"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

En las ocasiónes de encontrarme con la frase "habrás visto" in la oración, me lo sorprede esto: por qué aquí se usa "habrás visto" en vez de "verás" o "has visto"? Por ejemplo:

1. Como habrás visto en las noticias, el gobierno de Estados Unidos ha prohibido la entrada ....
2. Si has intentado ir al blog habrás visto que está en Mantenimiento.
3. El vídeo más bonito que habrás visto en mucho tiempo
4. La fiesta de verano más increíble que habrás visto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El futuro perfecto se usa para **conjeturar sobre una acción pasada**.

- Habrás visto...

significa: Supongo que has visto...

En cambio, "has visto" **afirma** que la persona **vio** algo, y "verás" apunta a una **acción en el futuro**. Veamos algunos ejemplos:

1a. Como habrás visto en las noticias, el gobierno de Estados Unidos ha prohibido la entrada a los teatros. (supongo que lo has visto)

1b. Como has visto en las noticias, el gobierno de Estados Unidos ... (sé que lo has visto)

1c. Como verás en las noticias, el gobierno de Estados Unidos ... (todavía no lo has visto, pero lo verás en el futuro)

2a. Si has intentado ir al blog, habrás visto que está en mantenimiento. (supongo que lo has visto)

2b. Si has intentado ir al blog, has visto que está en mantenimiento. (estoy seguro de que lo has visto, no hay chances de que no lo hayas visto)

2c. Si has intentado ir al blog, verás que está en mantenimiento: INCORRECTA. Para que sea correcta, debiera ser: Si intentas ir al blog, verás ...

3a. El vídeo más bonito que habrás visto en mucho tiempo (que supongo que has visto)

3b. El vídeo más bonito que has visto en mucho tiempo (que sé que has visto)

3c. El vídeo más bonito que verás en mucho tiempo (en el futuro, no verás otro más bonito por mucho tiempo)

Answer (score 1):

En español, uno de los usos del futuro (tanto simple como compuesto) es el [futuro de probabilidad](https://www.gramaticas.net/2016/09/el-futuro-de-probabilidad.html), que expresa probabilidad de que la acción de la que se habla esté teniendo lugar en el presente (con futuro simple) o haya tenido lugar en un pasado no especificado que forma parte de un momento que aún no ha terminado (con futuro compuesto).

Ejemplos:

> Ahora que sabes la verdad, te **darás** cuenta de la gravedad de la situación.

Expresa probabilidad de que el interlocutor se esté dando cuenta en el momento en el que se habla.

> Estos días **habrás oído** a mucha gente hablar todo el rato sobre el virus.

Expresa probabilidad de que el interlocutor haya oído a la gente hablar sobre el virus en los últimos días (marco temporal no terminado: se usa en los casos en los que, cuando se quiere expresar certeza en vez de probabilidad, se utiliza el pretérito perfecto compuesto).

¿Por qué no se usa **"verás"** en tus ejemplos 1 y 2? Porque no se refiere al presente ni al futuro, sino al pasado: "Como habrás visto [últimamente]...", "Si has intentado ir al blog [estos días] habrás visto...".

¿Por qué no se usa **"has visto"** en esos ejemplos? Porque el autor del mensaje no tiene certeza de que el destinatario "haya visto". Solo lo supone.

Los ejemplos 3 y 4 pueden verse también como futuro de probabilidad, o pueden entenderse como un pasado referido al futuro: "en el momento en que lo veas, no habrás visto ninguna otra cosa más increíble". ¿Por qué no **"verás"**? Con "verás", pasaría a significar "en ningún momento futuro verás otra cosa más increíble". ¿Por qué no **"has visto"**? Porque todavía no ha ocurrido.